# "in more better way" vs "more in better way"

Tags: grammar, word-order, indian-english

I am new to English. I have two sentences below. I want to know which has better grammar and is preferable for use.

> They can help in more better way.
>
> They can help more in better way.

#### Context:

I am working on support. When a user sends a request, at that time I have to decide whether I should deal with this request or pass it on to another Support Team. At that time, to escalate the issue, I have to write something to the user (requester). For this I have to chose one of the above sentences to say that another support person may have better knowledge in the requested technology.

Comment: In first sentence, you are asking *more* for a better way and in the second sentence, you are asking *more* for a help. Nevertheless, the article is missing.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatically incorrect, because *way* is countable, you need an article. (I might personally say, *They can help more and they can help better.*) As far as I can tell, it seems like a lot of people on the web use "in more better way" and "more in better way" can also be found, which reminds us that we cannot always trust search results. (Neither of them can be found in Google Ngram and COCA, both are a more reliable corpus.)

Comment: Could you please provide more context? If you did, then people would have better information, and *they could help you more.*  Or in other words if you give more information, *they can better help you.*  In what *way* you might think?  They can help you more *by providing answers that better address your questions (that's the way they can help you more).*

Comment: Context given and Explanation given in detail in Update section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer update for question marked "UPDATE (17th Feb 2014)":**

Restricted between only the two options, the first one is preferred, and fixed grammatically (minimally) as follows:

- They can help you better.  ("More better" is redundant.  See **Note** below.)

A more idiomatic way of saying this would be one of the following:

- They can better assist you with this issue.
- They can assist you better.
- They can assist you better than I can.  (very formal)

However, I would question why you need to defer to others as "better".  It certainly depends on your manager and situation, but speaking for American culture, the following would probably be better:

- **Good**: To best serve you, I am referring you to level 2 support.
- **Better**: To best serve you, this ticket is being escalated to level 2 support.
- **Best**: To best serve you, this ticket is being escalated to level 2 support. However, if you have any concerns with your support level at any time, please do not hesitate to contact me.

**Note that "more better" is redundant:**

- = more [ better ]
  = more [ higher quality ]
  = more [(higher) quality ]
  = more [(more high) quality ]
  = more more high quality

---

**OLD ANSWER BELOW**
.
.
.

**1. Definitions**

**More help** = Additional help in certain areas.  Can imply better but not necessarily.
**Better help** = Improvement in one or more qualities of help (faster, more thorough).  Can imply more help, but not necessarily.
**Way** = Specific methods used.

**2.  Try to identify your needs in terms of the following:**

1. "What is better?"
2. "More of what?"
3. "By what method (way)".**

**3. Examples:**

- Even though the new guy doesn't have the same depth of knowledge in SQL Server Management, the new guy can help you more to get your business going.  (The new guy has a wider skill set and that's what you need.  He's a better match for you in the opinion of the person saying this.)
- There's a guy I know that can help you better. (A little odd construction but ok in context in conversation.)
- There's a guy I know that can help you better with your taxes.  (Sill odd but a little better.)
- There's a guy I know that can help you better prepare for your taxes.  (Good. "better prepare" is a more specific "way" than "better with".)
- There's a guy I know that is better at icon design.  I think he can help you more than the guy you have.  = GOOD
- There's a guy I know that can help you more and better.  = Bad
- There's a guy I know that can help you more with your website.  He has more experience and better prices.  In fact, his service is better too; he's company is on call 24/7! (VERY GOOD)

Comment: +1 for the definitions - those themselves clarify the matter!

Answer (score 3):

"*They can help in more better way*" is incorrect.  This is because *more* and *better* are both comparatives and a sentence should not contain two.  It is a similar error to saying "*Today is more hotter than yesterday*".

"*They can help more in better way*" is almost correct.  As has been said in comments to the question, "*They can help more in a better way*" is preferred.  The interpretation is that they are helping more and that they are doing it in a better way than some manner which is implicit.

You could say "*They can better give more help*", which I believe conveys your intended meaning.

Comment: "preferred" implies a choice between 2 valid options. There is no such choice since one of the options is right and the other one is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Saying *more better* is wrong, because *better* already means *more good*.

The correct English depends on what meaning you're trying to express, which isn't clear from your question.

Here are some possible sentences and what they mean.

> Bob helped me a bit, but later John helped me in a better way.

This means that John's help was better than Bob's. Perhaps it was more useful, or more specific.

> Bob helps me, but John helps in a much better way.

John's help is a lot better than Bob's.

> John helps more in a better way.

John helps more **and** the help that he gives is better.

It would probably be better in English to choose a more specific adverb than "better", so we know why the help is better.

e.g.

- Suzie tried to help, but Jack's help was more useful.
- Suzie was quite busy in the morning but she helped more in the afternoon.
- If I knew more about what you wanted, I could be more helpful.
- If I knew more about what you wanted, I could be of more help. (same meaning as the previous example)